# ElasticSearch Stream NEW INCOMING documents to clients

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this usecase:

I receive ca 500 documents of cars (brand, model, color, airbag yes/no, etc.) **per second** and I am storing these in ElasticSearch. It works perfectly.

Then, I have a webclient, which searches for, example, all yellow BMW or blue Mercedes cars with airbags. This also works perfectly and in milliseconds.

But to receive the new cars, the user has to hit refresh. I want the results to popup immediately, so **streaming** the result to the users browser (via websockets).

Therefore my server logic (java at the moment, but I can switch to whatever I want) would have to **poll ElasticSearch** every second or so. **This does not seem like a good solution to me.**

Also, I do not have only one client but maybe thousands, so I am concerned about scaling.

So is there any way of streaming the results to the end user by taking into account, that new documents come in all the time.

If this is not possible with ElasticSearch, do you suggest something else? Apache Kafka for example is excellent at streaming, but (as far as I know), not with filtering the results.

Thank you!

Comment: Similar context here, we started using logstach in order to know if new element were present in es to send a message, after that, we develop our own application who is requesting es every Xs, if new documents are present, this application post them to our clients.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. So you are POLLING elasticsearch, if I understood it correctly. Does it scale? How many clients are polling elasticsearch? Thx

Comment: Well instead of pulling for every client, i got one application pulling es, if needed, it send updated data to each clients. Also take a look to logstach, could help you a lots.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you tell me how many often your query ES per second? I am a little bit concerned about scaling. But it seems like you have practical experience here. Thx!

Comment: I have 7 differents querries, i request 3 of them every 2000ms, the others like 5 to 30s. In my opinion, the real question about new elements are the .Refresh when you index, refresh are really coslty for es, so if you upsert like 10000 elements in one second and you want to refresh them instant, you could have trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for your details. Unfortunately, that does not allow me to conclude if it would work for me, because I plan to have >1000 clients querying ES every second or so. Indexing is not a problem, my setup to index the documents is in production for >6 months now without issues. We are using hosted ES from http://elastic.co in a small cluster and could upgrade it.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to have one application pulling ES, and pushing (if news items are found) to your 1000+ clients :).

Comment: Yes and no. If all 1000+ clients would consume the same data, yes. But my 1000+ clients have 1000+ DIFFERENT queries and this is something I am concerned of regarding scaling. But unless I have a better idea, I might try that in a lab setup.

Comment: Indeed, didnot notice the different querries. What a mess :) !